# manual installation of gcc

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, archlinux

i dont have internet connection, so i installed gcc on my linux system manually through its debian package. but i am not able to compile any c code. 
here is my sample c code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
printf("Hellp world");
return 0;
}
```

the error that it shows:

```
ocpe@blrkec241972d:~$ gcc -o hello hello.c
hello.c:1:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
hello.c: In function âmainâ:
hello.c:4: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function âprintfâ
```

I think i have not installed all the dependencies of compiler. Plz suggest me descriptive way to install it correctly..

Comment: remove <stdio.h> and write ` extern int printf (const char *format, ...); `

Comment: It seems like you don't have stdio.h, or you don't have it in correct folder. Check if you have stdio.h file in gcc include directories (/usr/local/include/ or /usr/include/)

Comment: Apparently you are missing stdio.h in one of predefined include paths of GCC. See http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html

Comment: Which linux distro? If not debian, I've a suggestion: use the distro's package manager not other tricks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming by "installed manually", you mean "using `dpkg -i`", then you need to also install `libc6-dev`. I suggest further installing, at very minimum, `build-essential` and everything it depends on.

Debian actually has a few programs to help with offline package installation. One option is of course to use CD/DVD images. Another is to use something like apt-offline.

Answer (score 0):

What about this `gcc -Wall hello.c -o hello -I/usr/include/stdio.h`?

You can see your include search path by using:

```
echo | gcc -v -x c -E -
```

On my Ubuntu Linux machine i can see this output for the previous command:

```
#include \"...\" search starts here:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/include
/usr/local/include
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/4.6.1/include-fixed
/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu
/usr/include
```

**EDIT** :

Install `build-essential`

Download from here : http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/i386/build-essential/download (assume you are 32 bits), and install dowloaded package like this:

```
dpkg -i build-essential.deb
```

Comment: using this command gives the same error
`gcc -Wall hello.c -o hello -I/usr/include/stdio.h`
error:
`hello.c:1:19: error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
hello.c:3: warning: return type defaults to âintâ
hello.c: In function âmainâ:

hello.c:4: warning: implicit declaration of function âprintfâ

hello.c:4: warning: incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function âprintfâ`

Comment: I found stdio.h at these locations on my system, tried adding those paths, but dint work.

`ocpe@blrkec241972d:~$ find /usr/lib| grep stdio.h`

`/usr/lib/perl/5.10.1/CORE/nostdio.h`

`/usr/lib/gcc-4.4.3/fixincludes/tests/base/stdio.h`

`/usr/lib/gcc-4.4.3/libssp/ssp/stdio.h`

`/usr/lib/gcc-4.4.3/gcc/testsuite/gcc.dg/cpp/usr/include/stdio.h`

`/usr/lib/gcc-4.4.3/libstdc++-v3/config/io/basic_file_stdio.h`

`/usr/lib/gcc-4.4.3/libstdc++-v3/config/io/c_io_stdio.h`

`/usr/lib/gcc-4.4.3/libstdc++-v3/include/c_compatibility/stdio.h`

`/usr/lib/gcc-4.4.3/libstdc++-v3/include/tr1/stdio.h`

Answer (score 0):

On my Debian system, the header files are in another package `libc6-dev`. You're probably missing that (and some others as well, I would guess).